# E[Z=XY] not matching with Z = Binom(4,p)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

I tried to multiply two independent binomials, each distributed with $n=2$ and probability p. So using the piecewise function for $P(XY),$ I have $$P(Z=z) = P(XY = xy) = \sum_{xy=z} z \cdot P(X=x, Y=y)$$ leading to $Z \sim \text {Binom}\ (4,p)$. But using the piecewise function to compute $E[XY]$...I got $4p^2.$ But if $Z \sim \text {Binom}\ (4,p),$ the expectation should be $4p.$ Could someone let me know where I went wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "...leading to $Z\sim \text{Binom}(4,p)$" is wrong.  $Z=3$ is an impossible value for the product of 2 integers in the range 0 thru 2, but is a possible $\text{Binom}(4,p)$ value.

Answer (score 1):

If $$X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(2,p), \quad Y \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(2,p), \\ Z = XY, \quad W \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(4,p),$$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $$\begin{align*}
\Pr[Z = 1] &= \Pr[XY = 1] \\
&= \Pr[(X = 1) \cap (Y = 1)] \\
&= \Pr[X = 1]\Pr[Y = 1] \\
&= \left(\binom{2}{1}p^1 (1-p)^{2-1}\right)^2 \\
&= 4p^2(1-p)^2. \end{align*}$$
However,
$$\Pr[W = 1] = \binom{4}{1} p^1 (1-p)^{4-1} = 4p(1-p)^3 \ne \Pr[Z = 1],$$ demonstrating $W$ and $Z$ are not identically distributed.

In fact, it is the **sum** of independent and identically distributed binomial random variables that are also binomially distributed, not the product.

Comment: @Ubanstan You have already been told twice, and shown in two different ways, that if $Z = XY$, then $Z$ is not binomially distributed, so I don't understand why you persist in making incorrect claims such as $\Pr[XY = z] = \Pr[X+Y = z]$.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\begin{align*}
\mathsf P(Z=0)
&=\mathsf P(X=0,Y=0)+2\cdot \mathsf P(X=0,Y=1)+2\cdot \mathsf P(X=0,Y=2)\\\\
&=(1-p)^4+4p(1-p)^3+2p^2(1-p)^2
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
\mathsf P(Z=1)
&=\mathsf P(X=1,Y=1)\\\\
&=\mathsf 4p^2(1-p)^2
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
\mathsf P(Z=2)
&=2\cdot\left(\mathsf P(X=1,Y=2)\right)\\\\
&=4p^3(1-p)
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
\mathsf P(Z=4)
&=\mathsf P(X=2,Y=2)\\\\
&=p^4
\end{align*}$$

Hence we get the pmf

$$ p_{Z}(z)=  
\begin{cases} 
(1-p)^4+4p(1-p)^3+2p^2(1-p)^2 & z=0 \\
4p^2(1-p)^2 & z=1 \\
4p^3(1-p) & z=2 \\
p^4 & z=4 \\
\end{cases} $$

It would behoove you to check that the respective probabilities sum to $1$.